# Write to `forkpty` child process: `less` pager

Tags: c, ipc, execvp, pty

I'm trying to use `forkpty` to `execvp` the `less` pager program, and then from the parent process write some text in such a way the child `less` process will get that as its input.

I've been doing some research on how to accomplish this, but I can't get something to work using `forkpty`, while I do using `pipe` and `fork`.

What happens is that I see no output and then the program exits normally.

EDIT: I noticed that if I read from `master` after `forkpty` I see "Missing filename ("less --help" for help)" from `less`, but how come `$ echo test | less`, works fine then? Changing `exec_argv` to pass `"-"` to `less` still has the same original problem (no output).

Am I missing something obvious?

### Working code using `pipe` and `fork`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int read_write_fds[2];

    if (pipe(read_write_fds) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!pid) {
        if (close(read_write_fds[1]) == -1) {
            perror("CHILD: close write");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (dup2(read_write_fds[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1) {
            perror("CHILD: dup2 read STDIN_FILENO");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (close(read_write_fds[0]) == -1) {
            perror("CHILD: close read");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        char* exec_argv[] = {"less", NULL};
        execvp(exec_argv[0], exec_argv);
        perror("CHILD: execvp");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (close(read_write_fds[0]) == -1) {
        perror("PARENT: close read");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char text[] = "Hello, world!\n";
    char* text_ptr = text;
    size_t bytes_left = sizeof(text) - 1;

    while (bytes_left > 0) {
        ssize_t bytes_written = write(read_write_fds[1], text_ptr, bytes_left);

        if (bytes_written == -1) {
            perror("PARENT: write");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        bytes_left -= bytes_written;
        text_ptr += bytes_written;
    }

    if (close(read_write_fds[1]) == -1) {
        perror("PARENT: close write");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) == -1) {
        perror("PARENT: waitpid");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Non-working code using `forkpty`

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pty.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int master;
    pid_t pid = forkpty(&master, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("forkpty");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!pid) {
        char* exec_argv[] = {"less", NULL};
        execvp(exec_argv[0], exec_argv);
        perror("CHILD: execvp");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char text[] = "Hello, world!\n";
    char* text_ptr = text;
    size_t bytes_left = sizeof(text) - 1;

    while (bytes_left > 0) {
        ssize_t bytes_written = write(master, text_ptr, bytes_left);

        if (bytes_written == -1) {
            perror("PARENT: write");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        bytes_left -= bytes_written;
        text_ptr += bytes_written;
    }

    if (close(master) == -1) {
        perror("PARENT: close");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) == -1) {
        perror("PARENT: waitpid");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm able to use both `forkpty` and `pipe`+`fork` to read from a child process, such as `ls`.

Comment: amongst other problems, this line: `#include <wait.h>` should be: `#include <sys/wait.h>`

Comment: @user3629249 "among other problems" -- I'm glad you can spot them easily, I can't and that's I posted my question here. If you could be so kind as to point them out, that would be great. Also, `less` doesn't need a filename if there's content on stdin, `echo test | less`, and that's what I'm trying to achieve here. EDIT: You removed your comment on `less` needing a filename, but I'm leaving mine here.

Comment: this llink: http://www.apuebook.com/apue3e.html is to an available book that contains code and explanation on how to use the `forkpty()` function.

Comment: I removed the comment on `less` when I realized that I was wrong.  The referenced book (which I don't like using references to books) explains everything you need to know about the `terminal` layer of linux

Comment: go to the link I provided, drill down through the `source code` link, download to your computer, extract the files.   Generally, what you need to create is a driver for the pseudo terminal and then setup up communication with that driver from your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Minor nit: in the child after `fork()` you should use `_exit()`.)

The reason you see no output here is because the child's stdin, stdout, and stderr are all attached to the new PTY. You need to read from the master and do something with the data.

Comment: (1) Why should I use `exit()`? It's already exiting `main()` via `return EXIT_FAILURE`, right?

(2) Hmm, I added code to read from `master` in the parent process after `forkpty` and I did see "Missing filename ("less --help" for help)". I thought this code would be similar to `echo test | less` where no filename is needed. Even after forcing `less` to read stdin by passing a `"-"` argument, the child still exists and I don't see anything. Any ideas?

Comment: @Márcio (1) Because that's equivalent to `exit()`, which you shouldn't do either. http://www.unixguide.net/unix/programming/1.1.3.shtml (2) `less` checks `isatty(stdin)`. If it's not a tty, it treats stdin as data and tries to open a real tty for control. If it is a tty, it wants to get data from elsewhere.

Comment: (1) Ah, I see, thanks, I didn't know that, good to know. (2) Oh, so my code would be able to control `less`, but not pass input data, which is why `less` complains there's no filename, since it's not getting any input. Correct?

Comment: @Márcio Right, you need a different mechanism to get data to `less`. You can create a [named pipe](https://dyn.manpages.debian.org/mkfifo.3.en.html), open it for write in parent, and pass that as the filename to `less`. Or you can create a `pipe` as before, and give the filename `/dev/fd/[number]` to `less`. (That's not guaranteed to work on all UNIXes, but at least on Linux it will.)

Answer (score 1):

here are the files involved from the link I provided:

Note: there are a lot of other files at the linked web page that you may find you need for this project:

example main function:

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <termios.h>

#ifdef LINUX
#define OPTSTR "+d:einv"
#else
#define OPTSTR "d:einv"
#endif

static void set_noecho(int);    /* at the end of this file */
void        do_driver(char *);  /* in the file driver.c */
void        loop(int, int);     /* in the file loop.c */

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int             fdm, c, ignoreeof, interactive, noecho, verbose;
    pid_t           pid;
    char            *driver;
    char            slave_name[20];
    struct termios  orig_termios;
    struct winsize  size;

    interactive = isatty(STDIN_FILENO);
    ignoreeof = 0;
    noecho = 0;
    verbose = 0;
    driver = NULL;

    opterr = 0;     /* don't want getopt() writing to stderr */
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, OPTSTR)) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'd':       /* driver for stdin/stdout */
            driver = optarg;
            break;

        case 'e':       /* noecho for slave pty's line discipline */
            noecho = 1;
            break;

        case 'i':       /* ignore EOF on standard input */
            ignoreeof = 1;
            break;

        case 'n':       /* not interactive */
            interactive = 0;
            break;

        case 'v':       /* verbose */
            verbose = 1;
            break;

        case '?':
            err_quit("unrecognized option: -%c", optopt);
        }
    }
    if (optind >= argc)
        err_quit("usage: pty [ -d driver -einv ] program [ arg ... ]");

    if (interactive) {  /* fetch current termios and window size */
        if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &orig_termios) < 0)
            err_sys("tcgetattr error on stdin");
        if (ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, (char *) &size) < 0)
            err_sys("TIOCGWINSZ error");
        pid = pty_fork(&fdm, slave_name, sizeof(slave_name),
          &orig_termios, &size);
    } else {
        pid = pty_fork(&fdm, slave_name, sizeof(slave_name),
          NULL, NULL);
    }

    if (pid < 0) {
        err_sys("fork error");
    } else if (pid == 0) {      /* child */
        if (noecho)
            set_noecho(STDIN_FILENO);   /* stdin is slave pty */

        if (execvp(argv[optind], &argv[optind]) < 0)
            err_sys("can't execute: %s", argv[optind]);
    }

    if (verbose) {
        fprintf(stderr, "slave name = %s\n", slave_name);
        if (driver != NULL)
            fprintf(stderr, "driver = %s\n", driver);
    }

    if (interactive && driver == NULL) {
        if (tty_raw(STDIN_FILENO) < 0)  /* user's tty to raw mode */
            err_sys("tty_raw error");
        if (atexit(tty_atexit) < 0)     /* reset user's tty on exit */
            err_sys("atexit error");
    }

    if (driver)
        do_driver(driver);  /* changes our stdin/stdout */

    loop(fdm, ignoreeof);   /* copies stdin -> ptym, ptym -> stdout */

    exit(0);
}

static void
set_noecho(int fd)      /* turn off echo (for slave pty) */
{
    struct termios  stermios;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &stermios) < 0)
        err_sys("tcgetattr error");

    stermios.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHOE | ECHOK | ECHONL);

    /*
     * Also turn off NL to CR/NL mapping on output.
     */
    stermios.c_oflag &= ~(ONLCR);

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &stermios) < 0)
        err_sys("tcsetattr error");
}
```

example looping function:

```
#include "apue.h"

#define BUFFSIZE    512

static void sig_term(int);
static volatile sig_atomic_t    sigcaught;  /* set by signal handler */

void
loop(int ptym, int ignoreeof)
{
    pid_t   child;
    int     nread;
    char    buf[BUFFSIZE];

    if ((child = fork()) < 0) {
        err_sys("fork error");
    } else if (child == 0) {    /* child copies stdin to ptym */
        for ( ; ; ) {
            if ((nread = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE)) < 0)
                err_sys("read error from stdin");
            else if (nread == 0)
                break;      /* EOF on stdin means we're done */
            if (writen(ptym, buf, nread) != nread)
                err_sys("writen error to master pty");
        }

        /*
         * We always terminate when we encounter an EOF on stdin,
         * but we notify the parent only if ignoreeof is 0.
         */
        if (ignoreeof == 0)
            kill(getppid(), SIGTERM);   /* notify parent */
        exit(0);    /* and terminate; child can't return */
    }

    /*
     * Parent copies ptym to stdout.
     */
    if (signal_intr(SIGTERM, sig_term) == SIG_ERR)
        err_sys("signal_intr error for SIGTERM");

    for ( ; ; ) {
        if ((nread = read(ptym, buf, BUFFSIZE)) <= 0)
            break;      /* signal caught, error, or EOF */
        if (writen(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, nread) != nread)
            err_sys("writen error to stdout");
    }

    /*
     * There are three ways to get here: sig_term() below caught the
     * SIGTERM from the child, we read an EOF on the pty master (which
     * means we have to signal the child to stop), or an error.
     */
    if (sigcaught == 0) /* tell child if it didn't send us the signal */
        kill(child, SIGTERM);

    /*
     * Parent returns to caller.
     */
}

/*
 * The child sends us SIGTERM when it gets EOF on the pty slave or
 * when read() fails.  We probably interrupted the read() of ptym.
 */
static void
sig_term(int signo)
{
    sigcaught = 1;      /* just set flag and return */
}
```

example driver:

```
#include "apue.h"

void
do_driver(char *driver)
{
    pid_t   child;
    int     pipe[2];

    /*
     * Create a full-duplex pipe to communicate with the driver.
     */
    if (fd_pipe(pipe) < 0)
        err_sys("can't create stream pipe");

    if ((child = fork()) < 0) {
        err_sys("fork error");
    } else if (child == 0) {        /* child */
        close(pipe[1]);

        /* stdin for driver */
        if (dup2(pipe[0], STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO)
            err_sys("dup2 error to stdin");

        /* stdout for driver */
        if (dup2(pipe[0], STDOUT_FILENO) != STDOUT_FILENO)
            err_sys("dup2 error to stdout");
        if (pipe[0] != STDIN_FILENO && pipe[0] != STDOUT_FILENO)
            close(pipe[0]);

        /* leave stderr for driver alone */
        execlp(driver, driver, (char *)0);
        err_sys("execlp error for: %s", driver);
    }

    close(pipe[0]);     /* parent */
    if (dup2(pipe[1], STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO)
        err_sys("dup2 error to stdin");
    if (dup2(pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO) != STDOUT_FILENO)
        err_sys("dup2 error to stdout");
    if (pipe[1] != STDIN_FILENO && pipe[1] != STDOUT_FILENO)
        close(pipe[1]);

    /*
     * Parent returns, but with stdin and stdout connected
     * to the driver.
     */
}
```

here is a makefile to put it all together:

ROOT=..
    PLATFORM=$(shell $(ROOT)/systype.sh)
    include $(ROOT)/Make.defines.$(PLATFORM)

```
ifeq "$(PLATFORM)" "solaris"
  EXTRALIBS=-lsocket -lnsl
endif

PROGS = pty

all:    $(PROGS)

pty:    main.o loop.o driver.o $(LIBAPUE)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o pty main.o loop.o driver.o $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGS) $(TEMPFILES) *.o

include $(ROOT)/Make.libapue.inc
```